# Android, Firestore, user data sharing across activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I use Cloud Firestore for the second time.

For bootstrapping my app, I anonymously authenticate users and I store additional information in a Firestore collection.

How can I store that data and share it across activities, without requesting Firestore in each activity ?

Regards

Comment: You can save locally, for that you have many options, shared prefs, database, a file...

Comment: That's quite dirty, I expected something with a user module and Dagger. I meant, I expect to call database at app startup, but not at each activity creation. Isn't there any library to manage that ?

Comment: Levi's comment is indeed the answer. But you should consider if it is really helpful to add such a storage layer. Firestore already caches the values in a database on the device, so the performance gains are likely minimal.

Comment: Yes, Firestore is wonderful !  But  If I can avoid to nest the auth request and the collection request in each fragment, it would be cleaner

Comment: You could create a SharedPreferences helper class, make it a dagger Singleton and inject it anywhere you like. Then you can save the data in the shared preferences, which is a faster way to save and retrieve data which is what you seem to be trying to achieve here. But as @FrankvanPuffelen said you need to consider if this is really worth it :)